# Find correlation between each group of rows for multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, correlation

I have monthly data for some shops and I want to find the correlation between each and every shop in the data frame. The data looks like this:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Shop': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'Month': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'Revenue':[10,20,30,20,40,80,10,40,90],'Cost':[6,14,21,10,20,34,7,26,78]})


   Shop Month Revenue Cost
0   1   1     10       6
1   1   2     20       14
2   1   3     30       21
3   2   1     20       10
4   2   2     40       20
5   2   3     80       34
6   3   1     10       7
7   3   2     40       26
8   3   3     90       78
```

As you can see for every shop I have 3 data points , 1 for each month and I want to find out the correlation among each and every shop for both the variables i.e. revenue and cost. So the output for variable **revenue** should look something like this:

```
        Shop1 .  Shop2  Shop3
Shop1 .  1 .      .6 .   .8
Shop2 .  .6 .      1 .   .7
Shop3 .  .8       .7 .    1
```

Similarly another coffecient matrix/dataframe for **cost** variable.

Comment: Are those correlations just made up? I seem to get different numbers

Comment: yeah they are made up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reshape your data so that your shops are the columns and the months are the row index.

```
df = df.set_index(['Shop', 'Month']).unstack('Shop') 

      Revenue         Cost        
Shop        1   2   3    1   2   3
Month                             
1          10  20  10    6  10   7
2          20  40  40   14  20  26
3          30  80  90   21  34  78
```

And now you can use `xs` to select the level you want and take the correlation:

```
df.xs('Revenue', axis=1).corr()

Shop         1         2         3
Shop                              
1     1.000000  0.981981  0.989743
2     0.981981  1.000000  0.998906
3     0.989743  0.998906  1.000000
```